# Define a Multi-Stage-Environment UI (Angular) in Kubernetes

Tags: user-interface, kubernetes, staging

A question regarding a multi-stage-environment in Kubernetes.

I got a dev,test,prod K8-Cluster, and I got environment variables that differ from stage to stage (like Backend-urls).

I was thinking of using the init-container for replacing the backend-urls per stage, so it's not hardcoded and you can change the urls, if something changes.

Is this an anti-pattern or would you just pack the backends together with the frontend (which is not really possible because we sometimes got more than one different backend-url)

Answer (score 2):

you should use configmaps to set the environment variables 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

example for angular:
[Configmaps - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080966/configmaps-angular)